# How to separate the json data to push to spreadsheet?

Tags: arrays, json

Here is the code so far. Keep in mind the data i am passing to the function   has already been parsed and stringified.

Here is my code so far. I just need to know how to push the data to the rows array and not how to move to a spreadsheet yet.
I keep getting an empty array: [17-03-29 05:07:48:351 PDT] [[null]]

```js
function pullJSON(data) {
  
 var rows = [];
 
 for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var dataS = data[i];
   rows.push([dataS.id]);
 Logger.log(rows);  
   
  }
```

[Here is the data that being passed to the function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OdIum.png)

Comment: Seems like you're trying to iterate through an object using `.length`. An object doesn't have a length. You could do something like: get the Objects' keys with `var keys = Object.keys(data)`, and then iterate through the array that returns. Then, `rows.push(data[keys[i]])`. Will that work?

Comment: Ok, i will try that. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: I just tried this but got no result:                                                           function pullJSON(data) {
 var keys = Object.keys(data); 
 var rows = [];
 
 for (i in keys) {
   rows.push(data[keys[i]]);
 Logger.log(rows);  
 }   
  
}